# Range function sending data to wrong row

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to add data to a worksheet, and while I know I've set up the Range function "correctly" (for a value of correctly that includes "worked every other time"), instead of labeling row 1 it's labeling row 2, and shifting the calculations in row 2 down to row 3. This is a problem only with this module in this worksheet.

I've tried the debugging tools, but they don't change the outcome or break anywhere. The first row hidden, nor is it frozen. And this happens whether or not I append ".value" after the range calls.

Weirdly, the second set of labels and calculations (starting at "With Calcs.UsedRange") are ending up in the correct cells. Code below:

```
Sub CalcGDD()
'Initialize
    Dim nb As Workbook
    Dim Clim, Vars, CC, Calc As Worksheet
    Dim LRow, RowL As Long

'Setup
    Set nb = ActiveWorkbook
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set Vars = nb.Sheets("Variables")
    Set CC = nb.Sheets("CoverCrop")
    Set Calcs = nb.Sheets("Summary")
    Set Clim = nb.Sheets("Climate")


'Calculations in Climate Sheet
    With Clim.UsedRange
        LRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("H1") = "Plant Day"
        .Range("I1") = "Harv Day"
        .Range("J1") = "Fall GDDs"
        .Range("K1") = "Spring GDDs"
        .Range("H2:H" & LRow & "").FormulaR1C1 = (...calculations elided...)
    End With

'Summarize
    RowL = CC.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    With Calcs.UsedRange
        .Range("A1") = "Year"
        .Range("B1") = "Fall GDD"
        .Range("C1") = "Spring GDD"
        .Range("D1") = "Total GDD"
        .Range("A2:A" & RowL & "").FormulaR1C1 = (...calculations elided...)

    End With
End Sub
```

Any ideas why Range("H1") is printing to H2? Thanks much.

Comment: I'd assume that `Clim.Usedrange` starts in row 2, not row 1. Is row 1 blank on that sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.UsedRange` is likely offsetting your addressing. Remove it in both `With` statements. If the `UsedRange` starts in row 2, then `"A1"` *in that range* refers to the top-left cell *in that range*. If you want to write to absolute cell address `A1` (i.e. not relative to where `UsedRange` starts), work off the actual worksheet cells instead.

> ```
> 'Calculations in Climate Sheet
>     With Clim.UsedRange
>         LRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
> ```

That `Cells` call is implicitly going against whatever the `ActiveSheet` happens to be. Qualify it with the `Worksheet` object you mean to work with - in this case, most likely the `With` block variable:

```
'Calculations in Climate Sheet
    With Clim
        LRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

See if [Rubberduck](http://www.github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck) (free, open-source VBIDE add-in project I manage) can spot more [implicit ActiveSheet references](http://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Details/ImplicitActiveSheetReference) (and [other potential issues](http://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/List) in your code, like these [implicit Variant variables](http://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Details/VariableTypeNotDeclared):

> ```
> Dim Clim, Vars, CC, Calc As Worksheet
> Dim LRow, RowL As Long
> ```

Also:

> *And this happens whether or not I append ".value" after the range calls*

That's because the `.Value` member call is [implicit](http://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Details/ImplicitDefaultMemberAssignment) if it's not specified.

Comment: UsedRange was the issue. Thanks!

Comment: @DataWrangler great! note that the implicit ActiveSheet reference can easily become one as well, and `LRow`, `Clim`, `Vars`, and `CC` are all implicit `Variant` - you'll want to address these issues as well.